# Remove zoom buttons from Google Annotation Chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to remove 1h, 1d, 5d from the zoom menu on my Google Annotation Chart:

[image]

I found one post that that indicated the way to accomplish this was by adding the following to the chart.draw function but it is not doing anything.  Please advise.

```
    chart.draw(data, options);
    $("#chart_div_AnnotationChart_zoomControlContainer_hour").remove(); 
    $("#chart_div_AnnotationChart_zoomControlContainer_day").remove();};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use chart option --> `displayZoomButtons`

```
var options = {
  displayZoomButtons: false
};
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['annotationchart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'WTI');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Nat Gas FOB US');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2015, 0, 1), 5, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 4), 1, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 7), 3, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 10), 5, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 13), 3, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 16), 7, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 19), 3, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 22), 4, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 25), 9, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 28), 8, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 31), 6, null]
  ]);

  var options = {
    displayZoomButtons: false
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks Very much!  Will accept the answer as soon as they let me.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can also hide specific zoom buttons with event listener (note how listener is added before `chart.draw()`):

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['annotationchart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'WTI');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Nat Gas FOB US');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2015, 0, 1), 5, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 4), 1, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 7), 3, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 10), 5, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 13), 3, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 16), 7, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 19), 3, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 22), 4, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 25), 9, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 28), 8, null],
    [new Date(2015, 0, 31), 6, null]
  ]);

  var options = {
    displayZoomButtons: true
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_container'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', hideUnwantedZoomButtons);
  chart.draw(data, options);
});

function hideUnwantedZoomButtons() {
    const buttons = document
        .getElementById('chart_container_AnnotationChart_zoomControlContainer')
        .getElementsByTagName('button');
    const threeMonthButtonId = 'chart_container_AnnotationChart_zoomControlContainer_3-months';
    let threeMonthButtonKey;
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        if (buttons[i].id === threeMonthButtonId) {
            threeMonthButtonKey = i;
        }
    }
    if (threeMonthButtonKey === 'undefined') {
        return;
    }
    for (let i = threeMonthButtonKey; i < buttons.length - 1; i++) {
        buttons[i].hidden = true;
    }
}
```

See working example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Alex_Default/j9vfnudg/4/)